# Подключение Qt к Visual studio 2012

Tags: qt, c++, visual-studio

Хотел попрограммить интерфейсы в Qt, но не знаю, как подружить библиотеки Qt с VS2012. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте установить это [Visual Studio Add-in](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/visual-studio-add-in).
Ну и, естественно, скачать-установить сами библиотеки Qt.

Comment: Я уже пробовал, ругается что версия не подхожит =/

Comment: Можно попробовать сделать как по ссылкеhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863466/how-to-set-visual-studio-2012-rc-compiler-for-qt-instead-of-mingw